# How can I create an animated GIF using ImageMagick 7?

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to follow the [Animation Basics](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/) tutorial for ImageMagick, but not having much luck.  It appears the tutorial is for version 6, and I'm using the latest version 7, so I assume things have just changed slightly since then and the tutorial is out of date.

The very first command is:

```
  convert -delay 100  -size 100x100 xc:SkyBlue \
          -page +5+10  balloon.gif   -page +35+30 medical.gif  \
          -page +62+50 present.gif   -page +10+55 shading.gif  \
          -loop 0  animation.gif
```

And it's supposed to produce this image:

[image]

I acquired the `balloon.gif`, `medical.gif`, `present.gif`, and `shading.gif` and ran the command myself, and I get:

[image]

The command succeeds, and without the images in the folder it fails, so it's obviously finding the balloon, medical, present, and shading source images, but it doesn't appear to use them in the output.  The background doesn't cover the whole image either.

**How can I make this command work on the latest ImageMagick?**

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with the syntax for version 7. I just ran this command with version "ImageMagick 7.0.3-5 Q16 x86_64" and it's working as it should for me.

Where did you get your ImageMagick from and what operating system are you using?

Comment: And what does it say for GIF when you run "identify -list format"? Are the source images displaying properly when you open them?

Comment: The GIF contains an out-of-range color: $ magick identify z*
zlIGE.gif[0] GIF 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2c 4.46KB 0.000u 0:00.000
zlIGE.gif[1] GIF 8192x8192 100x100+5+2573 8-bit sRGB 2c 4.46KB 0.440u 0:00.439
identify: corrupt image `zlIGE.gif' @ error/gif.c/PingGIFImage/929.
$ gm identify z*
gm identify: Invalid colormap index (index 3 >= 2 colors, zlIGE.gif).
gm identify: Request did not return an image.  Try adding `-depth 8` to your `convert` command.